# Sakadevan binds Lord Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas, bhakti

I have heard a story that in the period before war, when Krishna projects that even though he wishes peace, others like Bhima are going for war. Sakadevan points that by binding Krishna, one can stop war. Later he binds him by his devotional mind to prove his point. Krishna requests him to release him.
Which version of Mahabharata has this story.

Answer (score 3):

The story of Sahadeva binding Krishna comes from the Villi Bharatam, a Tamil version of the Mahabharata composed by the 15th century poet Villiputturar.  Here's what [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=d8k98lBxwM4C&lpg=PA50&dq=sahadeva%20binds%20krishna&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=sahadeva%20binds%20krishna&f=false) says:

> Thus Sahadeva binds Krishna with mental ropes in Villiputturar's Tamil Mahabarata.

And [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=kAjvBBzI_2sC&lpg=PA313&dq=%22long%20rope%20of%20his%20mind%22&pg=PA313#v=onepage&q=%22long%20rope%20of%20his%20mind%22&f=false) says that the story given by Villiputturar comes from an earlier Tamil poet named Perundevanar:

> The upshot of all this is a vivid bhakti tableau, traceable from Peruntevanar through Villiputtur to our drama, in which Krsna asks how Sahadeva could possibly bind him, and Sahadeva replies, in the words of the play, that he can do so through the "rope of knowledge" (nanakkayiru), or the "long rope of his mind [or heart]" (netumanak kayiru)[.]

The book also suggests that the story may have been inspired by the story of Krishna showing his Vishwarupa to the Kauravas, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7661/36).  In any case, if anyone's interested [this web page](http://ritsin.com/unknown-facts-from-mahabharata-indian-mythology.html/) gives the details of the story:

> Sahadeva, the youngest of Pandavas was a very wise person. He was a great astrologer who could predict things in advance.  Once Shri Krishna asked him that what should be done to prevent Mahabharata war. Sahadeva replied that Krishna himself must be tied down and imprisoned. He said that all Pandavas along with Duryodhana must be sent to forest and Karna must be made the king. In response, Krishna challenged him to tie him down, Sahadeva started meditating and envisioned Krishna as a small baby and tied him down.
>   Since Krishna could not move out of the bondage created by Sahadeva in his meditative trance, he blessed him with divine vision and then only Sahadeva released Krishna from the bondage.

It also seems to me to have some similarity to the story of Dadhipanda, which I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13744/36).