# Why is shiva called khandakarnan?

Tags: shiva, puranas, worship, tradition

Some temples shiva is worshipped in the form of "khandakarnam".Even shivaling is worshipped in the same temple.

Comment: See my question here for more information about Khandakarnan (Ghantakarna in Sanskrit): http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13633/36